# Bitwise operators in conditional statement

Tags: c, bitwise-or

I am trying to enter an `if` statement based on a `bit-wise` operator without changing the original bits, and am confused why what I have doesn't work.

I am checking if it least one of bits **7, 4, 2 are 0**.

Working code: (it changes the original bits, which I do not want)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    unsigned char ch = 0b11111111;

    ch = ~(ch | 0x6B);

    if(ch) {

        printf("%s\n", "YES");
    } 

    else {           

        printf("%s\n", "NO");        
    }

}
```

That prints `NO` (as it should) and prints `YES` if you change bit **7, 4, or 2 to a 0.**

Non-working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    unsigned char ch = 0b11111111;

    if(~(ch | 0x6B)) {

        printf("%s\n", "YES");
    } 
    else {

        printf("%s\n", "NO");
    }

}
```

I am pretty stumped as I think the two pieces of code are identical?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy to explain:

`0x6B` as you write it gets interpreted as a default integer (probably 32 bit). So `(ch|0x6B)== 0x000000FF==0b00000000000000000000000011111111`. Hence, `~(ch|0x6B) == 0b11111111111111111111111100000000`, which is not 0, hence is `true`.

If you, however, put that result into a `char`, only the lower 8 bits are saved, and hence `(unsigned char) ~(ch|0x6B) == 0`, which evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, you are testing a character value, after the m.s. bits of the calculation have been truncated.

In the second example `0x6B` is an integer, so `ch` is promoted to an int for the calculation and the m.s.bits (which you invert) are considered in the test.

There is an easier (and more obvious) way to test if any of bits 7,4,2,0 are set:

```
if ((ch & 0x95) != 0) { ... }
```